# How to request URL of previous page visited and store parts of it as a ForeignKey?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I have a django application that has an architecture:

```
Myapp.com/< uniquepageURL>
```

For posting  new things to the page:

```
Myapp.com/< uniquepageURL>/post
```

For commenting on a specific post on a page

```
Myapp.com/< uniquepageURL>/comment< ID# of the post>
```

For example, if you are commenting on the post that is stored in the database with an ID of 22 then the URL should look like:

```
Myapp.com/< uniquepageURL>/comment22
```

This is how I’ve decided to map my urls. Is there a better/simpler way to do it? The `< uniquepageURL>` is also the ForeignKey of the post object in my models. What I am having trouble with is figuring out how to use the request function in django to look at what the url was so as to gain information from it, namely for posts which uniquepage it is from so I can save the value into the foreignkey field and for comments which post ID it is a comment of. What would the views for each look like? 
Here is my urls.py.
For posts:

```
url(r'^(?P<uniquepageURL>[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*)/post/$', views.post, name='post')
```

for comments:

```
url(r'^(?P<uniquepageURL>[a-zA-Z0-9_./-]*)/comment(?P<post.pk>[0-9]*)/$', views.comment, name='comment')name='comment')ts:
```

I think the post.pk part is wrong since it returns an error. But I can fix that myself hopefully if I can figure out how to get the post section working at least.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that the `?P<uniquepageURL>` syntax indicates a named group; Django will attempt to match that name to arguments in the view function (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/urls/#named-groups).

So, to get that value passed to your view function, simply include a parameter `uniquepageURL`. Note that means `post.pk` won't work as a name; consider `post_id` as an alternative. (Though I supposed you could use a `**kwargs` construct and get at the value with `kwargs['post.pk']`).

That said, if you do need other information from the request URL, I think the value you are looking for is `request.path` (which presumes your signature is `def comment(request, uniquepageURL, post_id)` or similar.